# Ember.js controller method is returning the function as text

Tags: controller, ember.js

I have the following controller:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  location: (->
    location = this.city+", "+this.country
    return location
  )
```

And this in my template:

```
{{location}}
```

But rather than rendering a string such as "New York, USA", ember renders:

```
function () { var location; location = this.city + ", " + this.country; return location; }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to define it as a [Computed Property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/):

```
Whistlr.OrganizationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  location: (->
    location = this.get('city') + ", " + this.get('country')
    return location
  ).property('city', 'country')
```

Don't forget to use `get()` when you use the value of a property. In other words, use `this.get('foo')`, not `this.foo`. Also, since you use CoffeeScript your code is better written as:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  location: ( ->
   @get('city') + ", " + @get('country')
  ).property('city', 'country')
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. This was exactly what I needed.